# Why does this not work: INSERT SQL statement using "With ROW_NUMBER" . Error is Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'With'

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, with-statement

I am using this syntax which works in components separately but when I use it all together, it stops to work I get a syntax error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'With'. I am not sure why.

```
if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Assignments') is not null 
   drop table #Assignments
create table #Assignments
(
SerialNumber varchar(24) not null
)
insert into #Assignments (SerialNumber)
    With Row_Number as 
        (
        select SerialNumber,row_number() 
        over (partition by serialNumber order by serialnumber) as Row_Num
        from Monitor  
        where SerialNumber IS NOT NULL
        ) 
    select SerialNumber from Row_Number where Row_Num > 1
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, it includes an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-using-a-recursive-cte-in-an-update-statement) on how to perform a DML operation; you'll notice your error pretty quickly then.

Comment: Side note: partitioning and ordering by the same value is going to be nondeterministic, and your intent would be clearer if you did `order by (select null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid syntax.  When you use a CTE the WITH is the first part of the statement.

```
if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Assignments') is not null 
    drop table #Assignments;
create table #Assignments
(
    SerialNumber varchar(24) not null
);

    With Row_Number as 
        (
            select SerialNumber,row_number() over (partition by serialNumber order by serialnumber) as Row_Num
            from Monitor  
            where SerialNumber IS NOT NULL
        ) 
    insert into #Assignments (SerialNumber)
    select SerialNumber from Row_Number where Row_Num > 1;
```

Side note: make sure you include `;` after your statements when you are using CTE's.  The statement prior to `WITH` has to be terminated or you will get a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you @squillman. I see it now.